# Why don't Google Sheets graphs lay out my points correcty?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

When I try to make a simple graph of some points in a Google Sheets said points do not end up where I want them to in the graph. Using data like this I expect a straight line in my graph:

```
col A   col B
 1      0.5
 3      1.5
10        5
```

Instead the points are laid out as if the data was actually:

```
col A   col B
1       0.5
2       1.5
3         5
```

To be fair I have checked "Use column A as labels". But if I don't check that box I get two lines, neither a straight line.

How do I tell Google Sheets to use column A as `x` values and column B as `y` values for my graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired result edit your chart and change the type to `Scatter` and uncheck the `Use column A as labels`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My actual graph uses dates as the values for the x axis and the scatter type doesn't seem to work in my case. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Arlaharen yes but your question was specific for a (x, y) representation.. Date is another case..! You can convert the date to a number and do it like that.. :) Otherwise is a label

Answer (score 1):

The new update in Google Sheets is treating the data in Column A as text. Column A now has to be used as labels, but you also have to uncheck the box that treats column A as text. It's nonsensical. After the update, you have to click and unclick two things to get an x,y-scatterplot when in the past, it took 1 click.

Answer (score 0):

Select A1:B4, Insert > Chart... and change the chart type to Line chart:

[image: WA7117 example]